# Convergence of the series $\sum \sin (n^{-\alpha}) $ where $\alpha > 0$ is a given real number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I suspect that the series is convergent, since $\sin (n^{-\alpha}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$ However, thus far I see no test applicable to this series. Does comparison work here? A hint suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use $\sin (n^{-\alpha}) \sim n^{-\alpha}$ (if $\alpha > 0$).

Comment: Bingo! That is what I overlooked... The relation $\lim_{x \to 0}\sin x / x = 1.$ Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You also need the appropriate equivalence/dominance argument to use $\sum a_n < \infty \wedge a_n \sim b_n \implies \sum b_n < \infty$.

Comment: Yeah, the limit comparison test, I know that! Thanks so much. (Actually if $a_{n} \sim b_{n}$ then $\sum a_{n}$ converges iff $\sum b_{n}$ converges.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Alex Halm, a key to see the convergence of the series under consideration is the relation $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x/x = 1.$ In combination with the limit comparison test, which (roughly) says that if $a_{n} \sim b_{n}$ then $\sum a_{n}$ converges if and only if $\sum b_{n}$ does, we can find out when the series $\sum \sin (n^{-\alpha})$ converges.

Since $\sin (n^{-\alpha}) \sim n^{-\alpha}$ and since $\sum n^{-\alpha}$ converges if and only if $\alpha > 1,$ we thus conclude that the series
$\sum \sin (n^{-\alpha})$ converges if and only if $\alpha > 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\alpha\ge1,$ then for sufficiently large $n$ $$0\le\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)\le\dfrac{1}{n^{\alpha}} $$ therefore by the [Comparison Test......](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComparison_test&ei=nvMcVdKrKYiY8QXSm4GoCA&usg=AFQjCNFB1iPYI4LLP1S6jpsAvRYQfoe5XQ)

If $\alpha\le1,$ consider the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)$$